# TypeError: method() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, google-drive-api, typeerror

I am using python google drive api, python 2.7.10 on windows 10.

I am setting a instance variable to a drive service. The problem arises when I try to run one of the the drive's service's methods `self.service.files().list()`. I believe that python is passing both the object `self` and the string `"title = 'Door_Photos' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"`Is there away to stop python from doing this?

```
class doorDrive():

def __init__(self, scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
             secretFile = 'client_secret.json',
             appName = 'Door Cam'):
    self.SCOPES = scopes
    self.CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = secretFile
    self.APPLICATION_NAME = appName
    self.photoFolderId = ''

    creds = self.getCreds()
    http = creds.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    self.service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
    self.initFolder()

def getCreds(self):
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'drive-python-quickstart.json')
    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(self.CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, self.SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = self.APPLICATION_NAME
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def initFolder(self):
    folders = self.service.files().list("title = 'Door_Photos' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute()['items']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line is passing your query string directly to `list()`, but you should probably be passing it in by keyword, like this:

```
def initFolder(self):
    folders = self.service.files().list(q="title = 'Door_Photos' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute()['items']
```

Notice the `q=` in the front of your query now. That will make Python send it in as a keyword argument instead of a positional argument. I think your error is cascading further downward because the first argument to that function is actually `orderBy`.

You can see the specification here: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/python/latest/drive_v2.files.html#list